# Mongooose Middleware para encriptar senha em Schema

Tags: node.js, mongoose, bcrypt, middleware

Estou com uma dificuldade para por um Middleware no meu schema com mongoose. Coloquei ele como save e estou recebendo o erro de que ele não é uma função quando o chamo. Veja abaixo ambos os códigos:

```
schema.pre('save', function(next) {

console.log('this gets printed first');
console.log(user);

var user = this;

    if (!user.isModified('passwd')) return next();

    bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_WORK_FACTOR, function(err, salt) {
        if (err) return next(err);

        bcrypt.hash(user.passwd, salt, function(err, hash) {
            if (err) return next(err);

            user.passwd = hash;
            console.log(hash);
            console.log(user.passwd);
            next();
        });
    });
});
```

Tentei instanciar o model de duas formas diferentes acreditando se seria a forma que eu adiciono ele no respectivo script

```
//var model = mongoose.model('User');
var model = require('../models/user');

api.add = function (req, res) {
var user = req.body;
console.log(user);
model
    .save(user)
    .then(function(user) {
        res.json(user);
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).json(error);
    })
}
```

Segue o erro:

> TypeError: model.save is not a function
>       at api.add (/Users/admin/AndroidStudioProjects/4Party/api4party/app/api/user.js:43:4)

Se eu colocar como create e mesmo tendo esse middleware ele não criptografa a respectiva senha.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver, nesse caso era algum erro com a logica que eu estava usando, simplificando ela para um simples if e um salt gerado com bcrypt consegui encryptar o campo senha.

```
schema.pre('save', function(next) {
  if(this.passwd) {                                                                                                                                                        
      var salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10)                                                                                                                                     
      this.passwd  = bcrypt.hashSync(this.passwd, salt)                                                                                                                
  }                                                                                                                                                                          
  next()  
});
```